# GremlinPipeline issue with OrientDB

Tags: java, gremlin, orientdb

I have the following code snippet which I use to find the shortest path between two nodes:

```
GremlinPipeline<String, List> pathPipe = new GremlinPipeline<String, List>(v1)
            .as("similar")
            .out("similar")
            .loop("similar", new PipeFunction<LoopBundle<Vertex>, Boolean>() {
                //@Override
                public Boolean compute(LoopBundle<Vertex> bundle) {
                    return bundle.getLoops() < 5 && bundle.getObject() != v2;
                }
            })
            .path()
```

Now I wonder how can I print the results. I try this:

Iterator iter = pathPipe.iterator();
while(iter.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(iter.next());
}

But I have the following strange results:

```
[v[#9:0], v[#9:1], v[#9:0]]
[v[#9:0], v[#9:1], v[#9:2]]
[v[#9:0], v[#9:1], v[#9:3]]
[v[#9:0], v[#9:1], v[#9:4]]
[v[#9:0], v[#9:1], v[#9:5]]
[v[#9:0], v[#9:1], v[#9:6]]
[v[#9:0], v[#9:1], v[#9:7]]
[v[#9:0], v[#9:1], v[#9:8]]
[v[#9:0], v[#9:1], v[#9:9]]
[v[#9:0], v[#9:1], v[#9:10]]
[v[#9:0], v[#9:1], v[#9:11]]
[v[#9:0], v[#9:1], v[#9:12]]
[v[#9:0], v[#9:1], v[#9:13]]
[v[#9:0], v[#9:1], v[#9:14]]
[v[#9:0], v[#9:1], v[#9:15]]
[v[#9:0], v[#9:1], v[#9:16]]
```

Note that I am trying to find the shortest path between nodes v[#9:0] and v[#9:1].

Is there a problem on my find shortest path code or there is an other way to print my results?

I use oriented 1.6.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My gremlin-java/pipeline isn't as good as my gremlin-groovy, but one problem I see is that you aren't dealing with vertex equality properly in Java.  This part:

```
&& bundle.getObject() != v2
```

is valid for Groovy, but in Java I would write it as:

```
&& !bundle.getObject().equals(v2)
```

Comment: I can work with gremlin-groovy in with Java? Where can i find some more information?

Comment: I do mixed groovy/java projects pretty regularly.  There are a number of options, so it ultimately falls back to your project requirements.  Here's a few resources: https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/wiki/Using-Gremlin-through-Java#compiling-gremlin-groovy-from-java-to-create-pipes  and https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/wiki/Using-Gremlin-through-Groovy